# Error: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet and onRequestPermissionsResult

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-api-client

In a firebase crash report, I am getting this fatal error from one device on API level 23. 
I have been trying to get my devices to recreate the error but to no vail. Can anyone please point me on what the issue might be? Here are the relevant code sections:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.xyz.xyz/com.xyz.xyz.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:3758)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult (ActivityThread.java:3801)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400 (ActivityThread.java:157)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1405)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5551)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:730)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:620)
arrow_drop_down
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
com.google.android.gms.c.att.b ()
com.google.android.gms.c.aul.b ()
com.google.android.gms.c.auf.b ()
com.google.android.gms.location.internal.d.a ()
com.xyz.xyz.MainActivity.n ()
com.xyz.xyz.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult ()
android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult (Activity.java:6588)
android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult (Activity.java:6467)
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:3754)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult (ActivityThread.java:3801)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400 (ActivityThread.java:157)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1405)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5551)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:730)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:620)
```

OnCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ...
       // Create an instance of GoogleAPIClient.
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
        }

}
```

The onStart()

```
protected void onStart() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onStart() called");
    super.onStart();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
...
}
```

onResume()

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Within onPause(), we pause location updates, but leave the
    // connection to GoogleApiClient intact.  Here, resume receiving
    // location updates if the user has requested them.
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) startLocationUpdates();
```

onPause()

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // Stop location updates to save battery, but don't disconnect the GoogleApiClient.
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) stopLocationUpdates();

    super.onPause();
```

onStop()

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {

    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
```

}

onDestory()

```
public void onDestroy() {
if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy() disconnecting mGoogleApiClient");

            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
}
```

And finally the activity classes

```
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
               if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
   }



    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_LOCATION:
                // BEGIN_INCLUDE(permission_result)
                // Received permission result for LOCATION permission.

                Log.i(TAG, "Received response for LOCATION permission request.");

                // Check if the only required permission has been granted
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "LOCATION permission has now been granted.");

                    Snackbar.make(mLayout, R.string.permision_location_granted,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    setMyLocation();


                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "LOCATION permission was NOT granted. Setting city fixed location");

                    Snackbar.make(mLayout, R.string.permissions_not_granted,
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    setMyLocation();

                }
                // END_INCLUDE(permission_result)

            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    private void setMyLocation() {
        Log.d(TAG, "setMyLocation() called");
        Location lastLocation = null;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (lastLocation == null) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            }


        }
        if (lastLocation == null) {
            lastLocation = new Location("fixed");
            lastLocation.setLatitude(45.5017);
            lastLocation.setLongitude(-73.5673);
            lastLocation.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L);
        }
        updateLocation(lastLocation);
    }
```